# Index -1 for json key

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have been searching for answers to this for awhile and can't seem to see the obvious.

I'm attempting to return the value by index of a json string. Although the key appears to match, its returning -1 for index. I simply want the value, in this case "Ethan" for key username. I've verified that rows is valid json.

```
for (var r in rows) {
            table_body += '<tr>';
            for (var c in cols) {

                table_body += '<td>';
                //table_body += Object.keys(rows[r]);
                var idx = c;
                console.log(rows[r]);
                var o = rows[r]; //the object
                //var key = Object.keys(o)[idx];

                var key = cols[c].title;
                var index = Object.keys(cols).indexOf(key);
                console.log('key: '+key);
                console.log('index: ' + index);
                console.log('cols: ');
                console.log(cols[c]);
                console.log('c: ' + c);
                var value = o[index];
                table_body += value;
                table_body += '</td>';
            }
            table_body += '</tr>';
        }
        table_body += '</table>';
```

This is the output in the console showing "o", which is the json, the key, which is username, and the index of that key, -1

[image]

EDIT added more logs...[image]

EDIT
This is the json for rows...

```
[{"id":136,"userName":"ethan","halfDays":1,"fullDays":11,"approvedDept":null,"approvedExec":true,"type":"vacation","createDate":"\/Date(1332863557393)\/","approvedDeptDate":null,"approvedExecDate":null,"leaveBegin":"\/Date(1311570000000)\/","leaveEnd":"\/Date(1311570000000)\/","notes":"Beginning Balance","overage":false,"department":null,"reminderSent":true},{"id":381,"userName":"ethan","halfDays":0,"fullDays":1,"approvedDept":null,"approvedExec":true,"type":"sick","createDate":"\/Date(1336055792800)\/","approvedDeptDate":null,"approvedExecDate":"\/Date(1336021200000)\/","leaveBegin":"\/Date(1335502800000)\/","leaveEnd":"\/Date(1335502800000)\/","notes":null,"overage":false,"department":"Marketing","reminderSent":true}]
```

and cols...

```
[{ "title":"userName" },{ "title":"leaveBegin" },{ "title":"leaveEnd" }]
```

Comment: You're logging `rows[r]`, but searching for the key in `Object.keys(cols)`.

Comment: yes. I need the key "userName" from cols to then get the matching value from rows

Comment: Can you add `console.log(cols)`?

Comment: added logs above

Comment: So `cols` is array, why then `Object.keys(cols)`? It retruns just array indexes `0,1,2`.

Comment: There is no JSON involved here. JSON is a text format, and you're using objects and arrays. Perhaps if you searched without mentioning JSON that would bring more relevant results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the corresponding value to some field, consider the simpler example involving a dumb row:

```
const row = { username: 'a', leaveBegin: 'b', leaveEnd: 'c'}
```

consider the col:

```
const col = {title: 'username'}
```

you would get the value associated to username with

```
row[col.title] //'a'
```

now the array cols:

```
const cols = [{ "title":"userName" },{ "title":"leaveBegin" },{ "title":"leaveEnd" }]
const values = cols.map(({ title }) => row[title]) // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Finally for each row:

```js
const rows = [{"id":136,"userName":"ethan","halfDays":1,"fullDays":11,"approvedDept":null,"approvedExec":true,"type":"vacation","createDate":"\/Date(1332863557393)\/","approvedDeptDate":null,"approvedExecDate":null,"leaveBegin":"\/Date(1311570000000)\/","leaveEnd":"\/Date(1311570000000)\/","notes":"Beginning Balance","overage":false,"department":null,"reminderSent":true},{"id":381,"userName":"ethan2","halfDays":0,"fullDays":1,"approvedDept":null,"approvedExec":true,"type":"sick","createDate":"\/Date(1336055792800)\/","approvedDeptDate":null,"approvedExecDate":"\/Date(1336021200000)\/","leaveBegin":"\/Date(1335502800001)\/","leaveEnd":"\/Date(1335502800002)\/","notes":null,"overage":false,"department":"Marketing","reminderSent":true}]
const cols = [{ "title":"userName" },{ "title":"leaveBegin" },{ "title":"leaveEnd" }]
rows.forEach(row => {
  cols.forEach(({ title }) => {
    console.log(title, row[title])
  })
})
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you want to find index in array of objects. Use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
let cols = [{ "title":"userName" },{ "title":"leaveBegin" },{ "title":"leaveEnd" }];
let index = cols.findIndex(col => col.title == "leaveBegin");
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

`cols` is an array of objects, `Object.keys()` just returns an array of the array indexes, not the values of the `title` properties of the objects.

Use `findIndex()` to search for a matching object.

```
var index = cols.findIndex(obj => obj.title == key)
```

Alternatively, before the loops you could create an object that maps all the keys to their indexes, and use that.

```
var indexes = {};
cols.forEach(({title}, index) => indexes[title] = index);
```

Then in the loop you would do

```
var index = key in indexes ? indexes[key] : -1;
```